# Kendo grid column header

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid

I'm working with Kendo UI Grid and I want to know if it is possible to have both column and row headers, like this:

```
             colHeader1   colHeader2   colHeader3
rowHeader1
rowHeader2
rowHeader3
```

My grid:

```
$("#dataGrid").kendoGrid({
    editable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "name", title: "Name" },
        { field: "age", title: "Age" }
    ],
    dataSource: _dataSource()
});

var _dataSource = function () {
    return new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                crossDomain: true,
                url: url + "person",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        }
    });
};
```

My grid datasource will always have 30 records (fixed).

Comment: I'm afraid I never seen nothing like that before, have you any kind of demo with that behaviour?

Comment: I didn't see any demo with this behaviour on a data grid. I'm trying to make it look like a spreadsheet. Kendo UI has a spreadsheet widget, but it has a lot of things that I don't need and I can't find a way to remove. So I thought it was better to do it in a data grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`rowTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-rowTemplate):

```
rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#template").html())
```

And the template being:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <tr data-uid="#= uid #">
        <td class='k-header'>#: fixed #</td>
        <td>#: name #</td>
        <td>#: age #</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uDOpO)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: One question: you did this with a static datasource. How can I do it with a dynamic datasource? Should the header (fixed) come from my service? This is not a go way, because if I want just to display my grid, I would have to request from server.

Comment: @lpfx you can return it from your server or in anyway manipulate in javascript, [like this](http://dojo.telerik.com/uDOpO/2).